# php Installing in apache compilation error

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, lamp

Using solaris 10 Sparc platform and  solarisstudio12.3 c compiler.  Downloaded and compiled apache 2.4.6 successfully.  Downloaded php-5.5.5 and compiling but getting the below error When running make command.  How to resolve this error. 
Using the below commands

./configure --with-apxs2=/tsm/home/tsmtst01/apache/bin/apxs --with-mysql

./make

```
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 27: syntax error before or at: if
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 27: invalid source character: '\'
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 27: syntax error before or at: )
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 84: invalid source character: '\'
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 85: invalid source character: '\'
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 87: syntax error before or at: }
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 126: invalid source character: '\'
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 131: syntax error before or at: }
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 212: invalid source character: '\'
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 214: syntax error before or at: else
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 226: invalid source character: '\'
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 228: syntax error before or at: else
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 266: invalid source character: '\'
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass3.c", line 268: syntax error before or at: for
"/tsm/home/tsmtst01/php-5.5.5/ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_optimizer.c", line 281: warning: invalid white space character in directive
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass5.c", line 1: invalid source character: '\'
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass5.c", line 1: syntax error before or at: )
"/tsm/home/tsmtst01/php-5.5.5/ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_optimizer.c", line 286: warning: invalid white space character in directive
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass9.c", line 6: invalid source character: '\'
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass9.c", line 6: syntax error before or at: )
"/tsm/home/tsmtst01/php-5.5.5/ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_optimizer.c", line 291: warning: invalid white space character in directive
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass10.c", line 1: invalid source character: '\'
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass10.c", line 1: syntax error before or at: )
"/tsm/home/tsmtst01/php-5.5.5/ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_optimizer.c", line 292: syntax error before or at: <EOF>
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/block_pass.c", line 1224: warning: static function called but not defined: assemble_code_blocks()
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/block_pass.c", line 1903: warning: static function called but not defined: zend_t_usage()
"ext/opcache/Optimizer/block_pass.c", line 1355: warning: static function called but not defined: zend_jmp_optimization()

cc: acomp failed for /tsm/home/tsmtst01/php-5.5.5/ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_optimizer.c
*** Error code 1 make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `ext/opcache/Optimizer /zend_optimizer.lo'
```

Comment: is it fine if i skip the zend_optimizer. If so how can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of PHP bug [#65207](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65207), to disable opcache use `--enable-opcache=no` configuration flag - it is safe to disable, but decreases performance.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  Will try it and let you know.  Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working now.   Did the below way and make , make install  ran successfully export D_LIBRARY_PATH_64=/lib/64:/usr/lib/64  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib   ./configure --prefix=/tsm/home/tsmtst01/phpinstall --enable-opcache=no -with-mysql

Comment: I am unable to find the lib_php5.so  and  php ini file in the phpinstall directory after make install is completed successfully.  Do I need to add additional option while running configure script?

Comment: To build `lib_php5.so` or `lib_php5ts.so` you need to specify `--enable-embed=shared` configuration flag. `--with-config-file-path=PATH` will put `php.ini` into that folder.

Comment: I tried the below way the lib_php5.so got created in the apache/modules directory but php.ini file is missing. Some websites say -with-config-file-path specifies that PHP should look for php.ini file in the specified directory. Cant understand this setting.  ./configure  --prefix=/tsm/home/tsmtst01/phpinstall --with-apxs2=/tsm/home/tsmtst01/apache/bin/apxs   --with-config-file-path=/tsm/home/tsmtst01/phpinstall   --enable-opcache=no   --enable-

Comment: In httpd.conf configuration only enable the module LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so is mentioned in apache sites to make the php webpages work. why there is no configuration required in httpd.conf for php.ini file location path or phpinstall directory path. How does the apache knows the location of php.ini file and php install directory mentioned in the --prefix.

Comment: Able to find two ini files in the php source directory Do I need to renamte it to php.ini and copy it to a particular location after make install? tsm/home/tsmtst01/php-5.5.5> ls *ini*
php.ini-production
php.ini-development

Comment: My earlier posting of the command got truncated. ./configure --prefix=/tsm/home/tsmtst01/phpinstall --with-apxs2=/tsm/home/tsmtst01/apache/bin/apxs --with-config-file-path=/tsm/home/tsmtst01/phpinstall --enable-opcache=no --enable-so